# Sonarqube critical issue "Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one"

Tags: java, java-11

Hi I have a below method getting one critical sonar issue(Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one)

when I remove "Exception" and mention dedicated exception(IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException). At that time sonar raising a major issue "use generic one".

```
public Element createDomElement(String xmlRequest) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
        Document document = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultInstance();
        dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        if (documentBuilder == null) {
            throw new ABCException(null, "unexpected_error", "Error processing request", null,
                    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlRequest.getBytes(UTF_8)));
        }
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        return document.getDocumentElement();
    }
```

Not sure how I can resolve could you please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because ABCException is missing from throws? Will you please try below method signature and run the sonarqube?

```
public Element createDomElement(String xmlRequest) throws ParserConfigurationException, ABCException, SAXException, IOException {}
```

Edit 1 
Approaches to solve this issue

1. Throw only ABCException from createDomElement() method. Handle rest exceptions in createDomElement() itself. Not sure if its recommended one.

```
public Element createDomElement(String xmlRequest) throws ABCException {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
        Document document = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultInstance();
        try {
            dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new ABCException(null, "Parser Error", "Error processing request", null,
                    "Parser Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
//todo remaining part of method
}
```

2. Refactor code and divide createDomElement() method to follow Single Responsibility. This approach looks better than first one. Check this answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264068

Comment: Still getting Message Refactor this method to throw at most one checked exception instead of: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException, org.xml.sax.SAXException, java.io.IOException

Comment: Updated my answer with possible approaches